# How to classify a string based on a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dict as below:

```
strdirList = {'W':['WEST', 'WES', 'WE'], 'E': ['EAST', 'EA'], 'N':'NORTH', 
              'S':'SOUTH'}
```

Based on this dict, if I have a string, such as:

```
direction1 = 'WES EXAMPLE NORTH'
direction2 = 'EXAMPLE NORTH WES'
```

I want to get the return is

```
nameString1 = 'EXAMPLE NORTH'
direction1 = 'W'
nameString2 = 'EXAMPLE WES'
direction2 = 'N'
```

My current code is as below:

```
for e in range(len(directionList)):
    word = list(strdirList.keys())
    for i in range(len(word)):
        for n in range(len(strdirList[word[i]])):
            if directionList[e] == strdirList[word[i]][n]:
                directionList[e] = \
                directionList[e].replace(strdirList[word[i]][n], word[i])
```

My current code is ungraceful and doesnt work, is there any better and graceful way to resolve the problem? Many thanks!

update:
I want to just change the first element needed to be changed, and recorded its class, how can I do?

update2:
I try to slove by myself, but it is not just change the first one, the code is as below:

```
for i in range(len(directionList)):
    for sdic in strdirList.keys():
        if directionList[i] in strdirList[sdic]:
            directionList[i] = sdic
            break
for item in directionList:
    if item in strdirList.keys():
        directionList.remove(item)
        direction = item
        break
else:
    direction = ''
```

update3:
there is a my current way to slove the problem as below, but it just works for the flat dict:

```
def test(strdirList, direction):
    directionList = direction.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(directionList)):
        for sdic in strdirList.keys():
            if directionList[i] in strdirList[sdic]:
                directionList[i] = sdic
                return directionList
directionList = test(strdirList, direction)
for item in directionList:
    if item in strdirList.keys():
        directionList.remove(item)
        direction = item
        break
else:
    direction = ''
```

it do works for me now, but if anyone has a better graceful way, please write your answer as here!

Comment: Reverse the sense of your dictionary.

Comment: Also, look up the trie data structure

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for your warm help, how can I reverse the sense of your dictionary, can a list be the keys of a dict? And as for trie, I think may not suitable in this situation, because my data is not always has same node, such as WEST: WES, EST

Comment: You can have many keys with the same value.

Comment: What's `directionList` btw?

Comment: Why does `WES` be converted to `W`, but `NORTH` does not be converted to `N`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist directionList = direction.split(' '), in my update3, I still dont reslove the problem, it just works in a flat dir..

Comment: @RoadRunner because I just want to change the first element needed to be changed in the list, so I use return in my update3, but this code is just work in flat dict..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
strdirList = {'W':['WEST', 'WES', 'WE'], 'E': ['EAST', 'EA'], 'N':'NORTH', 
          'S':'SOUTH'}

direction = 'WES EXAMPLE NORTH'
new_direction = re.sub('\w+', lambda x:(lambda c:x.group() if not c else c[0])([a for a, b in strdirList.items() if x.group() in b]), direction)
```

Output:

```
'W EXAMPLE N'
```

Edit:

```
def get_direction(direction):
   flag = False
   for i in direction.split():
     if any(i in c for c in strdirList.values()) and not flag:
       yield [a for a, b in strdirList.items() if i in b][0]
       flag = True
     else:
       yield i

direction = ['WES EXAMPLE NORTH', 'EXAMPLE WES NORTH', 'EXAMPLE NORTH WES']
print(list(map(lambda x:' '.join(get_direction(x)), direction)))
```

Output:

```
['W EXAMPLE NORTH', 'EXAMPLE W NORTH', 'EXAMPLE N WES']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's do work for me. In addition, if it is possible to just change the first element and record its class based on your code? If you are interested, please see the edit problem, thanks again!

Comment: @YuchenHuang Glad to help! Is it guaranteed that an abbreviated direction, such as `WES`, will always be at the beginning of the input?

Comment: No, it will be in the any place of the string, such as :example0 WES North example1

Comment: it seems there is a bug, your code cannot change correctly in 'EXAMPLE WES NORTH'

Comment: @YuchenHuang What is your desired output for `'EXAMPLE WES NORTH'`?

Comment: 'EXAMPLE NORTH' and the class is 'W''

Comment: really really and sincerely thanks for your warm help, but may my explain is not so clear, the result I want is  ['W EXAMPLE NORTH', 'EXAMPLE W NORTH']. May my update3 code can be your reference. If there is any unclear pattern in my asking, I am really sorry.

Comment: there is still a bug, when I run ['EXAMPLE NORTH WES'], it return ['EXAMPLE NORTH W'], instead of ['EXAMPLE N WES']

Comment: @YuchenHuang The rules of your substitutions are very vague. Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, please see my recent edit.

Comment: current code is the perfect answer! thanks again and sorry for if I wasted any your time. I will notice and remember to your note makes problem clear, please forgive my careless as I am newbee in SOF..

Comment: @YuchenHuang No problem! Glad to help! Happy coding and learning!